# How does a probability distribution change when adding Gaussian noise?

Tags: probability, distributions, noise, gan

Instance Noise is a trick for stabilising Generative Adversarial Network (GAN) training. 
In [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.04490.pdf) paper, the authors say that (page 14, fig. 6)

> Instance Noise broadens the support of both distributions without biasing the optimal discriminator

I understand the intuition about how noise broadens the distributions and why this is beneficial for training. What I wonder is:

1. Is there any formal demonstration of this? What is the hypothesis behind it?
2. What happens if we use a different type of noise (e.g., not Gaussian)?

Thank you :)

Comment: I think you’re going to bias the optimal discriminator if you use noise that doesn’t have an expected value of 0. If you use noise with narrower support than you already have, I think you end up with the same support when you add the two distributions. Do you know about convolution of random variables. That’s going to come into play here.

Comment: see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties  -- note that if X and Y are independent, Var(X+Y) = Var(X) + Var(Y).

Comment: Thanks, that was easy :)